# How do I use pandas.Series.str while using df.iterrows()?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm confused how to access a dataframe's column and use `str.extract` while iterating through a dataframe with `df.iterrows()`

I have the following:

```py
for index, row in data_normalized.iterrows():
    print(row["assignment_name"].str.extract(r"^(\d+[/\.-]\d+[/\.-]\d+)(?:\s|$)")[0]))
```

but I'm getting the error `'str' object has no attribute 'str'`. I know `row` is a Series but how do I designate that I want to use `str.extract` on a specific field, which is `assignment_name` in this case?

Comment: Why do you need `iterrows` ? What's issue with `data_normalized['assignment_name'].str.extract(...)` ? You get the error because `row["assignment_name"]` is just a python `str`.

Answer (score 0):

@Psidom is right. You don't need .iterrows() for this

But if you need it for something else and can't do away with it then you can try this

```
for index, row in data_normalized.iterrows():
    print(row["assignment_name"].extract(r"^(\d+[/\.-]\d+[/\.-]\d+)(?:\s|$)")[0]))
```

Since row['assignment_name'] is already an str you didn't need a `.str` again